# Extending the base class of a hierarchy tree

Tags: c#, inheritance, extend

How can I extend a base class of a hierarchy tree to provide extra functionality based on encapsulated (`protected` values) where all children of this base class can benefit from these extensions?

---

Consider the following hierarchy of types.

[image: Hierarchy]

The dots indicate more classes that introduce extra types (`<T1, T2, T3>`, then `<T1, T2, T3, T4>` etc).

If you want to use this code, you should extend one of the lower classes (either `SimpleValidator` or `SectionedValidator`) and insert the model(s) you want to validate as the type argument(s).

Now a user might decide they want some extra functionality on the `Validator` class, i.e. the base class. But since everything is encapsulated, you cannot create extension methods since they can only access public properties/methods.

Extending `Validator` by inheriting from it is also a no-go because that would mean users will have to go through the whole boiler-plating themselves by writing all the typed variants again.

I'd ideally like to inject a class in-between `Validator` and `Validator<...>`, but I don't think this is possible in C# in an elegant/user-friendly way.

Comment: This isn't possible in general -- if your extension changed protected state, you'd potentially be breaking the child classes, and encapsulation's supposed to guard against that. If your extension is strictly read-only (never changes state of any object) then it would be safe, but the type system can't accommodate that. You can increase the visibility of members some more by using `protected internal`, but then your extension must live in the same assembly.

Comment: Consider also the #1 solution to every problem in software engineering (and also the #1 cause): add more layers. If `Validator` is now holding methods/state that would be really convenient to have available externally, maybe there should be more classes that allow us to duplicate/replicate the handy things that it does without needing to have, or be, an instance of `Validator`, and *those* get public interfaces that `Validator` (and any other interested party) can use. In other words, extract useful stuff to other classes and make `Validator` more of a facade.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide the whole "boiler plate" hierarchy as a [T4 template](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates) similar to some variants of how Entity Framework classes are generated, so users would be free to adapt them however they like? And/Or maybe work with [partial classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) (your "in-between" class), where users can provide their "other parts".

Comment: @JeroenMostert, could you give an example of how to layer it up further? Theoretically I understand it, but I don't see how I could do this in C#.

Comment: @Corak, partial classes would be interesting, but they only work within the same assembly. A user that gets my code via for example a Nuget package won't be able to add functionality to it. And I'll look into the template stuff. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what's in `Validator` or what kind of extension you envision, so that's hard. The basic idea is, as always, to shift around control: have `Validator` call methods on some object `Validator { void Foo() { usefulFooThatHasPublicMethods.Widgetry(); } }`, which is instantiated (somehow, some way) with internal state from `Validator`, or which gets a convenience `internal` constructor so it can wrap a `Validator` directly. Basically, I'm saying that what is `protected` now would need to get a properly supported `public` interface, by extracting new classes that everyone can use.

Comment: Of course, this doesn't help if `Validator` is not under your control and you want a user to be able to do this willy-nilly. That's the drawback of regular O-O: encapsulation means classes are extensible, but only in strictly regulated ways. If you misjudge the kind of extension necessary, you're out of luck. Page through the GoF book of design patterns to see if some structural pattern will fit in your case (adaptor, visitor, bridge).